# Keeping my char in scope, and handling it

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a function that converts a relative path (e.g. "log\crash.txt") to the full path (e.g. "E:\Program\log\crash.txt"). The function is:

```
string_t GetAbsPath(string_t relPath)
{
    char abs[1024];

    //Get the working directory
    GetCurrentDirectory(1024, abs);

#pragma warning(disable:4996)
    //Add a slash and content folder
    memcpy(&abs, strcat(abs, "\\content\\"), 1024);
    //Append it to the relative path
    memcpy(&abs, strcat(abs, relPath.c_str()), 1024);
#pragma warning(default:4996)

    return abs;
}
```

`string_t` is a class I wrote, its basically a wrapper for a `const char*`. My problem is, (and I sort of anticipated this...) is that when the function returns, `abs` goes out of scope, and the `string_t` that gets the returned value is now empty/junk. In a situation like this, I would normally just use `memcpy` to copy it into a pointer that won't go out of scope. But the issue there is, that pointer (which would be the `const char*` in `string_t`) would need to be `delete[]`'d. `string_t` doesn't have a destructor to begin with. I could write one and `delete[]` it there, but that posses another problem:

If I create a `string_t` like this:

```
string_t crash = "New[] isn't called! Ahh!";
```

When I go to `delete[]` it in the destructor, the program will crash because new[] was never called.

I could `delete[]` the `const char*` in the function that calls `GetAbsPath`, like this:

```
void LoadModel(string_t relPath)
{
     string_t fullPath = GetAbsPath(relPath);
     . . .
     delete[] fullPath.c_str();
}
```

But I know that if I come back to the code later, I'll be like "Why is that `delete[]` there", or I'll add it when it isn't needed... and well the pointer is, there's a lot of room for error there.

What can I do to keep that char in scope (I'm guessing this can only be done with pointers), and make sure that allocated memory gets cleaned up? There has to be a way, because std::string keeps everything clean, and it has features like concatenation, something my `string_t` doesn't even have. I appreciate any help here, because I'm at a loss...

Comment: Maybe the `string_t` isn't the right type to be using as the return type, precisely because it doesn't have the necessary destructor.  It looks like a 'one way' type; you can pass it into a function, but you can't get it back reliably if the memory to be passed back must be allocated.  If the data to be passed back is itself immutable, then you can use `string_t` OK.  Have the function return a `std::string` in some shape or form (`const std::string &`?).

Comment: Get rid of the `memcpy`s. They're broken (`memcpy` can't handle overlapping input and output). Also, there's no need to copy the data where it already is. Just call `strcat` to append onto a string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What you said gave me an idea. Would it be a good idea to make the type always use `new[]`, therefor always use `delete[]`? What I mean is, in the constructor, if you used `string_t("Foobar")`, it would allocate space for the string (6 chars + terminator)(using `new[]`) and copy that string ("Foobar") into it. That way, `delete[]` will always need to be called.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I try to just use `abs = strcat(...)` it gets mad at me because I the expression isn't a modifiable lvalue. I didn't think I could assign a char* pointer to a char[] array.

Comment: Just call `strcat`. Get rid of the `abs =`. You've already appended onto the string, what more do you want to do? (Think about it, `strcat` must append in place. Where else could it put its result?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh, I see. I feel like I should have known that... Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three choices:

1) Decide that `string_t` will always own the string it points to and it will be responsible for deallocating it. Have the constructors allocate/copy.

2) Decide that `string_t` will never own the string it points to and code calling it will always be responsible for deallocating it if necessary.

3) Decide that `string_t` will support both models and will need a flag to decide whether to call `free[]` or not in its destructor. Calling code will have to tell `string_t` whether to allocate/copy or whether to just stash the pointer.

Make sure to follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Or better yet, just use `std::string` which consistently takes option 1 and thus you can just use it without worrying.

Comment: I just realized what you said in choice 1, your answer allows me to feel safe with it. Thanks you!